# Django admin add a custom js every time user click on an element

Tags: javascript, django, django-admin

In my django admin project i have to trigger a .js file every time an user change a select field value.
In my admin/change_form.html page i add:

```
{% block extrahead %}{{ block.super }}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'admin:jsi18n' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/admin.js' %}"></script>
    {{ media }}
{% endblock %}
```

and in my admin.js:

```
​document.onclick = function(){
    console.log("test for admin.js");
}​
```

but in my browser console related to 'document' part of code i get:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

How can i use javascript code from django admin add/edit page?

so many thanks in advance